# Xposed cannot load an Xposed Class

Tags: android

I have an Xposed class in a separate Java file as well as other, non Xposed classes in other files.

I do have an xposed_init with the same package as in the Xposed class file which is the same as in all other files and in the manifest.

There are no red lines and no errors. I clean the project then I rebuilt the project and then run. The Xposed Installer says I have to reboot after Android Studio 1.2 runs the project on the device. I do see the project with the name as the package and `-1` or `-2.apk` in `/data/app`. Regardless, Xposed v54 cannot load the Xposed class from the apk.

Here is the error.log file from `/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer` of the device :

```
Jul 19, 2015 5:18:21 AM UTC
Loading Xposed v54 (for Zygote)...
Running ROM 'KXC21.5-40' with
fingerprint 'motorola/condor_retca/condor_umts:4.4
.4/KXC21.5-40/48:user/release-keys'
Loading modules from /data/app/stevenstanleybayes.proximitysensor-2.apk
Loading class package
stevenstanleybayes.proximitysensor.ProximitySensorXposed

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "package
stevenstanleybayes.
proximitysensor.ProximitySensorXposed" on path: DexPathList[[zip
file "/data/app
/stevenstanleybayes.proximitysensor-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/vendor/li
b, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56
)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.loadModule(XposedBridge.java:421)

    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.loadModules(XposedBridge.java:386
)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:120)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your app and Reinstall it again. Not updating of dex files happens a lot of time.

Edit :
Happy you got your code working. 
Yeah xposed_init isn't a java class, it doesn't require 'package' tag in front. It just requires full class name with package

About the log error, are you sure you are looking in

```
/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/log/
```

Sorry, can't comment, not enough points.

Comment: Uninstalled. Rebooted. Checked error.log. Because the application was not checked in Xposed Installer and, therefore, not installed by the Xposed Installer, error.log was OK. Then, run the app from Android Studio. Checked Xposed Installer. Rebooted. The problem was the same. Then, uninstalled. Built an apk with Android Studio. Copied to /sdcard/Download. Manually installed with ES File Explorer. Checked the apk in Xposed Installer. Rebooted. THE SAME PROBLEM. Please, help and advise. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have Android KitKat 4.4.4, API 19, SDK 19 on MotoE XT1023 and XposedBridgeAPI-54.jar. I am not sure whether this jar runs with API 22 and up. I have searched the web for an older jar but I have been unable to find such. The project is built for API 19. I remember some message to say API 22 or higher is required. I do not recall whether this was after I installed the jar and for the jar. I deleted the jar, downloaded the same new one and put the new one. The same problem.

Comment: Changed the name of the Xposed class. All lowercase. The same problem.

Comment: I have not tried to make the Xposed class a different module but may. I wonder whether anyone knows whether this is a good idea?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    } Changed to this. The same result.

Comment: Just to make sure XposedBridge jar does not compile but is just referenced.

Comment: dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
} Changed to these dependencies. Also, made the XposedBridge file a separate module with right click -> Make a Module. The same result. Whatever I try, fails.

Comment: Make a sample clock color changing Project from tutorial and check if it works. And there should be no problem with jar. The program is unable to find the class. Can you please also post xposed_init content and the Xposed class content in the question

Comment: Please, read the answer. The problem has been solved. I made a simple program which works fine. The important thing was to put just the full name of the CLASS in xposed_init. The full name of the class contains the name of the package and then the name of the class. Because of copy and paste, I pasted the word " package " in front which does not make sense because the name of the CLASS is necessary and the name of the class does not contain the word package and then blank. This means, in xposed_init, one must write Name.Name.Name and not " package Name.Name.Name ".

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED :

I have removed the string " package " from the xposed_init and this solved the problem. Thus, instead of :

package TheNameOfThePackage.TheNameOfTheClass

xposed_init contains :

TheNameOfThePackage.TheNameOfTheClass

without the word " package " in front of the names as Android Studio usually puts and requires.

Now, the custom class seems to load OK and XMain where zygote is init generates a novel.

Regardless, the custom class with the test code works OK. The debug.log file is generated. However, the application does not seem to write in the file and the debug.log only says :

d.xposed.installer/log/debug.log

inside.